# OCaml return unboxed float from C function with bytecode compiler

Tags: c, ocaml, ffi

I have a very simple function that calls `time(2)` in order to get the epoch time and returns it as an unboxed OCaml float.

The platform here is OS X 10.12.6 and I've tested using OCaml versions 4.03.0 and 4.04.0 .

Here is `libunixtime.c`

```
#define CAML_NAME_SPACE
#include <time.h>
#include <caml/memory.h>

#define IGNORE_UNUSED(x) ( (void)(x) )

CAMLprim double
ocaml_unixtime(value unit)
{
    IGNORE_UNUSED(unit);
    return (double) time(NULL);
}
```

The OCaml code, `unixtime.ml` looks like this ... it returns an unboxed float and indicates to the compiler that it doesn't perform any OCaml-side allocations.

This function takes less than 5 arguments, so it seems like implementing it once and using that for both the byte code compiler and native compiler should be fine (https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/intfc.html#sec397).

```
external unixtime : unit -> (float [@unboxed]) = 
  "ocaml_unixtime" "ocaml_unixtime" [@@noalloc];;

let () = Printf.printf "%f\n" (unixtime ())
```

This example works fine with the native compiler (although I'm a little concerned that the cast to `double` is not *exactly* the right thing to do but It Works On My Machine).

```
% ocamlopt unixtime.ml libunixtime.c
% ./a.out
1506195346.000000
```

However, when compiling with the bytecode compiler and attempting to run, I get a segfault immediately.

```
% ocamlc -custom unixtime.ml libunixtime.c
% ./a.out
Segmentation fault
Exit 139
```

Does the bytecode compiler not support unboxed floats? How do I figure out why the behavior differs between the bytecode and native compilers?

Comment: The cast to `(double)` is redundant and can be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your code seems to be missing a `CAMLparam` call for the `unit` value. This is necessary so that the GC knows about it, see [section 19.1](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/intfc.html#sec423).

But there's another more important bug: the bytecode version cannot use unboxed functions ([section 19.10](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/intfc.html#sec449)), so you'll have to provide an alternative implementation for the bytecode compiler that returns a boxed value using `caml_copy_double` and `CAMLreturn`.

Comment: Why do I need a `CAMLparam` call for the `unit` value? I was under the impression that a) `CAMLparam` is not needed for immediate things like `int`s or `char`s and b) `()` is immediate.

Comment: That makes sense, you probably don't needed indeed in that case. It's a good habit to always put it, though.